# PySide QFTP put only uploading 35-40 bytes

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

When I use QFTP's put command to upload a file it only uploads around 40 bytes of the specified file. I'm catching the dataProgress signal and I'm getting the progress but the total size of the file is only read to be around 40 bytes. Is there anything wrong with my code, or is it a problem on the FTP server's side?

Here is my upload function:

```
 def upload(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Upload File', '.')
        fname = QIODevice(filename[0])
        dataname = filename[0]
        data = os.path.basename(dataname)
        #data = data[data.find("/") + 1:]
        print data
        print fname
        if not self.fileTree.currentItem():
            self.qftp.put(fname, data)
        elif "." in self.fileTree.currentItem().text(0):
            self.qftp.put(fname, self.fileTree.currentItem().parent().text(0) + data)
        elif self.fileTree.currentItem().text(0) == "/":
            self.qftp.put(fname, data)
        else:
            return
```

Alright, figured out what I needed to do. I needed to create a QFile and read all of the bytes from that file and then pass that to the put command.

```
def upload(self):
    filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Upload File', '.')
    data = QFile(filename[0])
    data.open(1)
    qdata = QByteArray(data.readAll())
    file = os.path.basename(filename[0])
    print data
    if not self.fileTree.currentItem():
        self.qftp.put(qdata, file, self.qftp.TransferType())
    elif "." in self.fileTree.currentItem().text(0):
        self.qftp.put(qdata, self.fileTree.currentItem().parent().text(0) + file)
    elif self.fileTree.currentItem().text(0) == "/":
        self.qftp.put(qdata, file)
    else:
        return
```

Comment: What ends up in the file on the FTP server?

Comment: Tested this with a text file, and the content was the full path to the location the file was uploaded from i.e. C:/Users/jake/Desktop/TEST.txt

Is there a part of my code that would do this?

Comment: Had a guess at an answer given the current contents of your file on the server

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `data = os.path.basename(dataname)` means data is always a string containing the name of the file. Try changing this to be an open fileobj by using `data = open(os.path.basename(dataname), 'rb')`

**edit**

Looking at `PySide.QtNetwork.QFtp.put(data, file[, type=Binary])` and `PySide.QtNetwork.QFtp.put(dev, file[, type=Binary])` - the order of arguments is **data/dev** *then* **file** - so it's the wrong way around in your code...

Comment: When I do this I'm unable to pass data to the put function because data needs to be a QByteArray or QIODevice. I think I figured out the problem: When I pass a QByteArray to the put function it writes the content of the QByteArray to a file with a name on the server. I need to pass the QIODevice to write the ACTUAL file to the server. There's a problem with this, though, because I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: The problem there was just my poor naming of variables. The types are in the correct places, but the names are reversed. I did figure out how to get it uploaded though. I'm going to edit my original question with what I did.

Comment: @user1500452 It's okay to answer your own question for that (in fact it's encouraged)